# Android: borders messed up on clickable view elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey folks. I have a strange problem with my EditView elements in an Android project I am working on.  I make the view clickable in the xml file and put an action listener on it to launch a Uri. No problem there.  What I'm finding though, is that the bottom of the view element disappears when the view is clickable.  Below is a screenshot of what I mean.  I added the bold/blue font to make the items stand out more, but it did  that before adjusting the font as well.

Since I can't post an image here, I've linked to it below.

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxAyDSR7j2blZWYzYWViYjctM2E0Yi00NWFiLTllYmQtMTA3YWI3YTBhYmEw&hl=en

Comment: Sorry, too much time between swing and android.  I'm working with TextView views, not EditView views.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks more like a scaling issue. Are you sure that simply removing the clickable attribute solves the problem? How is that pixel separation defined (margin, padding...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is related to bolding the text.  If I remove that, it does stop the problem. Looks like I need a better solution for pointing out clickable fields.